# Which one of these 5 pin 3 phase connectors is more standard?

Tags: voltage, connector, wiring

Images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHg5A.jpg
One is rated 16A "Dafr-164m" and another is rated 32A "Typ 2"
We have a 16A breaker quite a ways from our house ~50m.
We asked someone and they said they use both.
We have 230v, 380v 50Hz
We have to change the connectors because our house uses the old Soviet connector and... we have no incoming earth! Only 3ph+N because ~50% of the electrical wiring in my town is Soviet-era and there's no earth

Comment: Hi! This would be on-topic at [diy.se], but it needs a clearer explanation of your current situation and of the problem you're trying to solve. You can also include the photographs within your post instead of linking to them; the instructions for adding photographs are at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post.

Answer (score 1):

Either two of them, the difference is in rated current 16A or 32A. Usually the 32A is well suited for a medium/small machine, the power connected is 32*0.4*1.73 <= 22kW, while the smaller one is more frequenty in use, because is the minimal 3 phase connector, therefore all hand tools, small electric machines, P<=11kW goes on 16A connector. The conclusion is: probably you wil need more 16A connectors.
The 3ph+N, what you are reffering is a 3PH+PEN, it's normal in most places in the world, in EU also. At your main cabinet you should split this PEN wire into two wires PE and N. The distribution network is never 2PH+N+PE, you won't find this enywhere, its not a Soviet madness.